# About isotopy and homotopy

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory

Is there any English translation of following [paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1928.159.101/pdf) ?

Isotopie von Kurven auf orientierbaren, geschlossenen Flächen und ihr Zusammenhang mit der topologischen Deformation der Flächen.
**Reinhold Baer**

Comment: Try google translate. Up to certain mistakes, which are clear, this is a first help. I use it for Russian papers. Also sometimes it is enough to know 20 words of topology in German. For example "Kurve=curve", "geschlossenen Fläche=closed surface", "topologische Deformation=topological deformation" etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde . I use this but in this way we have very much wrongs.